# Слайдер на сайт

Tags: jquery, javascript, карусель

Добрый день. Заказчик потребовал сделать на сайт слайдер, все бы ничего, если бы слайдер не был под следующими критериями:

1. Слайдер должен центрироваться относительно экрана
2. Слайдер должен быть по всей ширине браузера
3. Изображения слайдера могут иметь разную ширину
4. Слайдер должен быть цикличным. После последнего элемента, должен сразу идти первый
5. По бокам должны быть предыдущий и следующий кусок слайда.

Без хоть одного пункта, заказчик не принимает. Я уже по всякому пробовал написать этот слайдер, все равно хоть по одному пункту не идет. Даже в интернете все искал, ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста, идеей или в интернете готовым решением. Спасибо.

Comment: так вы какой-нибудь код предоставьте и скажите какого пункта там не хватает.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже написал.

Answer (score 2):

[30 слайдеров контента на jQuery](http://yeap.narod.ru/js/022.html)

Выберите для себя который Вам нужен, правда необходимо будет его стилизировать под свои нужды.

А так согласен с [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), что у Вас не получается напишите по пункам.

Comment: Я пересмотрел все такие списки, но не нашел. Спасибо. Я вчера все же смог написать по всем пунктам.